# Scala type parameter inference fails for Nothing

Tags: scala, type-inference

```
scala> class A[T]
defined class A

scala> class B[T](a: A[T])
defined class B

scala> val b = new B(new A[Int])
b: B[Int] = B@1ff8982d
```

Great! I can create instances of `B` from instances of `A`. With one exception. For instances of `A[Nothing]` the type inference fails.

```
scala> val b = new B(new A[Nothing])
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A[Nothing]
 required: A[T]
Note: Nothing <: T, but class A is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
       val b = new B(new A[Nothing])
```

Specifying the type manually works.

```
scala> val b = new B[Nothing](new A[Nothing])
b: B[Nothing] = B@3aad5958
```

Should I file a bug for it, or is it an intentional trap to scare away programmers that lack sufficient resolve for Scala?

Comment: Oddly, `def f[T](a: A[T]) = 9; f(new A[Nothing])` works. But `def f[T](a: A[T]) = a; f(new A[Nothing])` fails again with the same `type mismatch`.

Comment: It's at least confusing, if not buggy. I would file a bug

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has been known and ignored as [issue SI-1570](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1570) since 2008. The assumption is that nobody uses Scala for anything serious.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the compilation feedback.  You need to declare A as being covariant in T, so that when you don't specify the type parameter during the construction of a new B, the compiler can infer that the A[Nothing] may be treated as type T (or treat the A[T] parameter as a T).  That's be basic idea behind covariance.

Comment: Sure, making it covariant would "make the error go away". But what is the cause of the error? Why does type inference work with `A[Int]` but not with `A[Nothing]`?

Comment: Could it be due to the fact that Nothing is "uninhabited" (from the Scaladoc), and is a direct subtype of Any, whereas Int is a direct subtype of AnyVal?

Comment: Yeah, it certainly has to do with how `Nothing` is a very special type. It's not a matter of `Any` vs `AnyVal` though, the example works with any type except `Nothing`. `class C; val b = new B(new A[C])` works.

Comment: If you define A and B as follows, then it works:    class A[T]; class B[_](a: A[_])